# Vbox Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Guest Freezes on a Windows 10 Host

Tags: 20.04, virtualbox, windows-10, freeze

The problem is very simple.

I am using Windows 10 as my primary OS, and as I work on Django web projects, I installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on an Oracle VirtualBox version 6.0.14 r133895, also inserting Guest Additions to adjust the resolution and enable bidirectional clipboard.

It works fine for one or two sessions, but after a while... when I try to open it again it completely freezes! It opens and boots perfectly... but it does not respond to my mouse or keyboard clicks AT ALL!

I tried reinstalling the system... and again... it works perfectly for one session (where I backed it up)... but then again it completely froze the next session. I deleted it and loaded the working backup... but even that was frozen.

None of the online solutions I found worked with me so far. Please help. Thank you and have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

How much RAM have you allocated to Ubuntu? I experienced freezes when Ubuntu is doing swap. You can see it on your Windows 10 when you open the task manager, then go to the tab "performance" and check the disk usage (on the storage where your VM is installed, of course). If the disk usage is near 100% that means the Ubuntu is swapping a lot.